# What happens when you believe in kufr thoughts

Tags: shirk, kufr, waswasa

Lately I have had a problem where I have severe waswas. I know that if you believe in these shirk/kufr thoughts then it takes you outside the fold of Islam. But the problem that I have is that I keep believing in these thoughts, and I don't know what to do about them. The thoughts come to me for the whole day, and even when I am praying. Then I have to break my salat because I believed in the shirk thoughts and I have to renew my shahada. Now I have to rush my salat before I can believe in another one of those those thoughts. I cant even sleep because of me believing them, and I get very frustrated about this and I get worried about this, because these are the last ten nights of ramadan. Am I still going to get punished for believing in these thoughts if I keep on believing them? I know that this is not just regular waswas, and that Allah might be angry with me for believing them. Is anyone else going through the same issue where they keep on believing these thoughts? Did any of you find a way to get rid of these thoughts. If so please let me know.

Comment: Are you certain you believe in it this could be shaitan trying to mess up with your head if these are doubts throw them in the dust bin and ignore them Insha’Allah all will help you I hope you get better soon

Comment: Yes I am sure that I believe in them. I try to ignore them but I cant the thoughts just keep coming.

Comment: Look up these thoughts on YouTube you will find informative videos that explain this Insha’Allah may Allah make things easy for you

Comment: Thank you may allah bless you. Ameen

Comment: Ameen happy late Ramadan and I hope you have good time with your family on eid al fitr

Comment: You too thanks-

Answer (score 0):

Saitan try to put bad thought in people's mind. A good people's protect themselves from committing any bad action due to influence of the thoughts and if you have done nothing due to influence of these bad thought. You no need to worry.

You are not the only one who have these kind of thought. Just ignore them. Its the act of saitan to miss guide you or make you confuse and it may put you in depression if not ignore.

Read Ayat Al qursy will help to get rid of these kind of thought.

Comment: Thank you a lot may allah bless you for this as well. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it appears you don't believe it. It is just a thought or confusion. just for example, Suppose if I believe in aliens, I would become sure that aliens are there. I won't ask anybody "is there any aliens? did I start believe in aliens?". I would absolutely know that yes, aliens are there.

What works best for me to get rid of such thought is just not "trying to forget". Each time I try to forget something, I have to pay attention to that thing. So the best way that works for me is just to ignore such popping up thoughts.

Comment: If a question is confusing/contradicting or the questionnaire is confused, you should flag the question as it **needs clarity/further information** rather than typing it.

Comment: @AbduRahman   Thank. I tried to comment but the comment section is locked for not having enough points. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: I tried to give the asker a friendly suggestion so that he or she can find ease from the difficult situation.

Comment: I have flagged the question for further improvement as per suggestion.